# Method to generate binary sequences with desired cross-correlation and autocorrelation properties

Tags: autocorrelation, cross-correlation

I am looking for a method to generate two binary sequences of length $N$ with the following properties:

- Very good cross-correlation for all shifts.
- Good enough autocorrelation for all shifts except zero delay (good enough means $\gg 1$ and $\ll N$).

I can even relax the constraint on the cross-correlation as follows:

- Very good cross-correlation for $\pm M$ shifts around zero delay, and no matter for the other shifts.
- Good enough autocorrelation for all shifts except zero delay.

Following publications of Dr Welch and Dr Sarwate, it is possible to obtain a set of $K$ sequences of length $N$ and norm $N$ with the following properties :
$$\max(θ_a,θ_c)≥N\sqrt{\frac{K}{NK-1}}  \approx \sqrt{N},$$
and
$$\theta_c^2 + \frac{N-1}{N(K-1)}\theta_a^2 \geq N,$$
where $\theta_a$ is the maximum autocorrelation and $\theta_c$ is the maximum crosscorrelation.

From that, I understand that it is possible to find two sequences whose cross-correlation is ideal ($\theta_c = 0$) and whose autocorrelation is good enough ($\theta_a \approx \sqrt{N}$).
However, I am not aware of a method or an algorithm to generate such sequences.
Could you provide some directions or point to a paper that would help?

Besides, by limiting the constraint on the cross-correlation to some shifts only, can we expect to reduce noticeably the maximum autocorrelation? Are there methods to generate such sequences?

Answer (score 4):

Flattered though I am that a short note (D.V. Sarwate, "Bounds on crosscorrelation and autocorrelation of sequences", *IEEE Trans. Information Theory*, vol. IT-25, pp. 720-724, 1979) that I wrote over 40 years ago is still receiving some notice, the OP's question is *way* too broad for this forum; people (not me!) have written whole *books* on this subject.

Neither Lloyd Welch nor I ever claimed that there exist sequence sets that meet these bounds exactly or almost exactly. Rather, *every* set of $K$ sequences of period $N$ must be such that $(1)$ and $(2)$ in the OP's question are satisfied. In particular, the OP's belief

> *From this*, I understand that it is possible to find two sequences whose cross-correlation is ideal ($\theta_c = 0$) and whose autocorrelation is good enough ($\theta_a \approx \sqrt{N}$).

is a false understanding. If two sequences are uncorrelated (that is, $\theta_c = 0$), then $\theta_a$ must be *at least* $\sqrt N$, but *it is not the case* that there *must exist* a pair of uncorrelated sequences with $\theta_a \approx \sqrt N$. My paper cited above gives examples of a set of $N$ sequences (the rows of a length-$N$ DFT matrix) for which $\theta_c = 0$ but $\theta_a = N$ which is much larger than the desired $\sqrt N$. Unfortunately, while smaller subsets do still satisfy $\theta_c = 0$, the maximum off-peak autocorrelation continues to cling to $\theta_a = N$. The paper also described the Frank-Zadoff-Chu sequences for which $\theta_c = \sqrt{N}$ and $\theta_a = 0$. Both sets are optimal with respect to these bounds.  The sequences in both sets are complex-valued, not binary.

For sets of $N$ *binary* sequences of period $N$, a bound due to Sidel'nikov tells us that $\theta_\max$ must be at least as large as $\approx \sqrt{2N-2}$. $\,\,$ *Gold sequences* of period $N = 2^{2n+1}-1$ essentially meet this bound ($\theta_\max $ equals $\sqrt{2(N+1)}+1)\approx \sqrt{2N-2}$, but for periods $N = 2^{2n}-1$, $\theta_\max$ is $\approx 2\sqrt{N}$ for Gold or Gold-like sequences. If $\theta_\max\approx \sqrt{N}$ is non-negotiable as a criterion for sequence design, then for $N=2^{2n}-1$, the *small set of Kasami sequences* has $\sqrt{N+1} = 2^n$ sequences with $\theta_\max= \sqrt{N+1}+1 = 2^n+1$. For more details, see D.V. Sarwate and M.B. Pursley, "Cross-correlation properties of pseudorandom and related sequences," *Proc. IEEE,* vol.68, pp.593-619, May 1980.

With regard to other queries in the OP's question, some work has been done towards the construction of of sequences whose *autocorrelation* values are small for small nonzero offsets (while larger bounds for large offsets are OK), but typically, small *crosscorrelation* values for small offsets while allowing larger values for larger offsets has not received much attention. The former problem is of interest because it makes fine-tuning of the synchronization process in spread-spectrum systems easier; the latter might be more of a niche problem for special systems with nearly synchronized times-of-arrival.